# Proper use of ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

```
TheLists a = new TheLists();

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TheLists>
{
    MyAdapter() 
    {
        super(ListPage.this, R.layout.list_row, R.id.sname, a);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code ?

I'm getting an error on the "super" line which says "the constructor ArrayAdapter(Listpage,int,int,TheLists) is undefined"

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass either a `TheLists[]` (Java array) or a `List<TheLists>` (implementation of `java.util.List`) as the final parameter, given your `ArrayAdapter<TheLists>` declaration.

Comment: Agreed. It would also help if we knew what TheLists was.